# FragmentController vs FragmentScenario

Tags: android, android-espresso, robolectric, android-fragmentscenario

Roblectric's `FragmentController` allowed us to drive the lifecycle of the `Fragment` to a desired state. It seems that `FragmentScenario` always takes the `Fragment` under test to its resumed state. One would assume that calling `moveToState(CREATED)` would take the `Fragment` back to through its `onCreate()`, but in reality, as per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing#drive-fragment-new-state), `moveToState()` simulates an external app interacting with the `Fragment` under test. This means that `moveToState(CREATED)` moves the `Fragment` under test through `onPause()` and `onStop()` as it would happen when a new `Activity` is launched.

> To drive the fragment to a different lifecycle state, call moveToState(). This methods supports the following states as arguments: CREATED, STARTED, RESUMED, and DESTROYED. This action simulates a situation where the activity containing your fragment changes its state because it's interrupted by another app or a system action.

Is it possible to somehow direct `FragmentScenario` to drive the `Fragment` to a desired state instead of always going through `onResume()`? How do we test that something happened inside `onCreate()` and not inside `onResume()` using `FragmentScenario`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle-states.svg

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to test something during fragment's onCreate, but I had the case to supply my fragment with fake viewmodel(mocking happy case, etc.) - you can do it as follows:

```
@Test fun yetAnotherTest(){

    val fakeViewModel = YourViewModel(fakeDependency1, fakeDependency2,...)

    val scenario: FragmentScenario<YourFragment> =
        launchFragmentInContainer {
            YourFragment().apply {
                viewModel = fakeViewModel
            }
        }
}
```

and some minor modifications

```
lateinit var viewmodel: YourViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    //if this is yetAnotherTest() run, line is skipped 
    if (!::viewModel.isInitialized) {
        //normal setup
        viewModel = provideYourViewModel()
    }
```

alternatively, you can provide [FragmentFactory](https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragmentfactory-ceec3cf7c959) for your fragment so you can test fragments with FragmentScenario more easily.

Comment: This requires modifying production code to accommodate tests and you still wouldn't know when the view model was interacted with. I found a solution that doesn't require that, but after having a [`discussion`](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/593) with someone from the Android test team, it seems this "limitation" is intentional.